# :hover works only when forced in the dev tools inspector

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

The :hover effect works only when forced via dev tools but not on mouse hover. 
I tried changing browsers from mozilla, chrome to safari but no luck 
Why is this happening? 
I want the text(mary...) to appear on the image as soon as i hover...

Here is my code,

```
.story {
    width: 75%;
    color: $color-black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: $color-white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 9rem 6rem;
    padding-left: 9rem;
    font-size: $default-font-size;
    transform: skewX(-12deg);
& > * {
    transform: skewX(12deg);
}
&__shape {
    width: 17rem;
    height: 17rem;
    float: left;
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    transform: translateX(-3rem) skewX(12deg);
    position: relative;
}
&__img {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1.4);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .5s;
}
&__caption {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
    transition: all .4s;
    color: $color-white;
    opacity: 0;
    &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

```
    <div class="story">
        <figure class="story__shape">
            <img src="/img/nat-8.jpg" alt="Blonde" class="story__img">
            <figcaption class="story__caption">mary smith</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: If the color of `&__caption` is white, you probably don't see it when you hover the element, no matter what the opacity is.

Comment: Since i am super imposing the text on image, it is visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the caption when you hover on the image, how about if you apply :hover to `&__shape`?

https://codepen.io/kreediam/pen/pojmEwJ

```
&__shape {
  width: 17rem;
  height: 17rem;
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  transform: translateX(-3rem) skewX(12deg);
  position: relative;

  &:hover {
    .story__caption {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, the caption does show for me in that pen, but I have to make sure to hover on the caption, which only takes up a small area compared to the image.

Comment: Thanks, it worked your way. I also tried my approach in codepen and it worked. However, why is it not working in my project i wonder? Can u give me an explanation for the same, it'll be highly appreciated. I just wasted my whole day figuring it out...

Comment: I have been there before and I feel your pain. :) :( Hard to say why it isn't working in your project. I suggest commenting out `opacity: 0;` to make sure the caption has content and that you're hovering on the caption, but then again it doesn't seem like hovering on the caption would be the experience you're going for.